# How do I assure that mouse pointer appears when mouse moves over form after commanding the drop down for a combobox to show?

Tags: delphi, combobox, dropdown, mouse-cursor

I have a problem where:

1. I have a form with just a combobox.
2. The combobox has focus and mouse is not hovering over the form when item 3 happens.
3. I trigger the combobox's drop-down list to show on a key-press event.

When the drop-down list is visible and then I move my mouse pointer over the form, the pointer is either invisible, shows that it is busy, or shows the resizing icon but does not turn back to a normal pointer when over the form.

Is there something that can be done to assure that, when the drop-down of the combobox shows, that the mouse pointer is visible when I move the pointer over the form?

I have tried:

- `Applicaiton.ProcessMessages` after showing the drop-down.
- Changing focus to the form the combobox is on after showing the drop-down.
- Adding `Key := #0;` after calling the drop-down to show.

  ```
  procedure TForm1.ComboBox1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  begin
    SendMessage(ComboBox1.Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, Integer(True), 0);
    Key := #0;
  end;
  ```
- Tried using a timer to trigger the drop-down within the key-press event.
- Tried using "SetCursor" after commanding the drop-down to appear.
- Tried using ".DroppedDown", but did not see any difference in result from that of "SendMessage".

I would hope to be able to show the mouse pointer after the drop-down is displayed, but it is hidden instead. Thanks for any suggestions.

(NOTE: This problem I have run into is not exlusive to Delphi. I was able to duplicate the issue using Visual C# 2017. Either way, if there is a way to correct this, it would be good to know).

Comment: Have you tried to do `ComboBox1.DroppedDown := True;` instead of `SendMessage`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I just tried your suggestion, but I get the same result regarding the mouse pointer (not refreshing when moving over the form). I wasn't aware of the property you mentioned though, so I will likely switch to that.

Comment: I can duplicate this with the combo on the run dialog of the OS. Not always though, generally only the first time I call the dialog. Looks like this is not Delphi related. Although one could set the cursor (through API) in response to WM_NCHITTEST (which is the only mouse message the form   would receive because of the capture) when the combo is dropped down, I wouldn't bother with it. Of course if you'd have a client aligned control over the form, then you'd have to handle it there.

Comment: Strange thing is that no one seems to call user32.SetCursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented to the question, the issue is not Delphi related. You can observe the same behavior in dialog boxes which contains a similar combo that the OS presents. One example is the one on the "run" dialog.

Involving a single environment, re-setting the cursor in an `OnDropDown` event handler fixes the problem.

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
begin
  winapi.windows.SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[Cursor]);
end;
```

Originally I tested the above because no one calls `SetCursor` after the drop down. Though it seems that no one calls it before either. So I have no idea about the cause or why the above fix works.

Comment: I misunderstood your earlier comment. I wasn't aware that there was a "DropDown" event. When I tried what you showed, that worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for clearing up with the comment. This is not the first time I fail to express, language probably...